# highcharts event handler for StockChart

Tags: highcharts, eventhandler

I was looking at http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.
I want a event handler to capture event when ever there is a change in the date range. 
This change in the date should be captured for all changes in date. For e.g. when the a button in rangeSelector is clicked or when a date is entered using the date picker or any other change in the graph due to a change in the date range. I need the Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',event.xAxis[0].min) 
                            and Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d', event.xAxis[0].max) values to be passed to the event handler. This is to show an additional graph with the new date range that has been selected. 
Regards
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `load` event on the chart, and then define your handlers for `rangeSelector` buttons:

```
chart : {
            events: {
                load: function () {
                    var chart = this;
                    var buttons = this.rangeSelector.buttons;

                    buttons[0].on('click', function (e) {
                        alert(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',chart.xAxis[0].min));
                        alert(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',chart.xAxis[0].max));
                    });
                }
            }
        }
```

This is for the first button of the `rangeSelector`: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2a5q4w/)

You can then add handlers for all the buttons

**EDIT:**

As [Sebastian Bochan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2021935/sebastian-bochan) said, you can use the `afterSetExtremes` and `setExtremes` events, it checks every action that changes the range in chart including `entering a date or dragging the cursor to select a date range`.

But the down side is when you use the `dragging` of the navigator, because it doesn't wait until you release the button of the mouse and triggers the event for every point change in the range. If you don't mind that, then it will be a great solution for you: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ag2a5q4w/1/)

Comment: But what about if you are entering a date or dragging the cursor to select a date range. In these scenarios, will there be any events generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can catch [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.setExtremes) / [afterSetExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering my question
I was trying to send inputs to a second Chart that I had on my along with the StockChart on the same page.I needed x-axis coordinate which I give as form elements to my second chart if anything changed in the date picker of the StockChart.
I used the following code as my solution.

```
chart: {
                            events: {
                                redraw: function (e) {
                                    fromDateStockChart=Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.xAxis[0].min);
                                    toDateStockChart=Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.xAxis[0].max);
                                    /*console.log('fromDateStockChart='+fromDateStockChart
                                            +' toDateStockChart'+toDateStockChart);*/
                                            form = document.searchFilters;
                                            form.date_from.value = fromDateStockChart;
                                            form.date_to.value = toDateStockChart;
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Regards
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

You should watch this example http://jsfiddle.net/ag2a5q4w/1/

```
 $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

        xAxis : {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes: function () {
                        alert(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.min));
                        alert(Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d',this.max));
                }
            }
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 1
        },

        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },

        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : data,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    })
```